# Ipython notebook link to external notebook

Tags: markdown, jupyter-notebook

I do not really know why, but I cannot link to files which are in a parent folder of the current working directory. I do start the notebook in the folder `04_documentation` and would like to refer to a notebook in `02_calculations`

The folder structure is:

- Experiment #12345

  - 01_data
  - 02_calculations

    - sma_fit.ipynb
  - 03_plots
  - 04_documentation

    - current working directory

The link looks like `[Link to working example](../02_calculations/sma_fit.ipynb)`

If the file is in the same folder or a subfolder, everything works fine. However, I cannot jump to a parent folder(404 error). Any ideas why that is the case ?

Comment: This has worked for me - try again. It's now 2016.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Ipython notebook (3 and 2.3.1) answer in github](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/7751)

Because of security reasons you are not allowed to do that.

> You could start the notebook in / but have the default dashboard be
>   something else. But by design navigating up --notebook-dir (default to
>   .) and going into folders that start with . is not possible.

Hope this is what you were trying.

Comment: This is not accurate. I've been able to link to external notebooks.